# Add a Truncated layer in Functional API model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I am trying to add truncation layer after Conv2D layer in the following code:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1))
conv = Conv2D(8, (5, 5), padding='same', strides=1, use_bias=False)(input_layer)
output_layer = Activation(activation='tanh')(lambda_layer)
output_layer = AveragePooling2D(pool_size= (5, 5), strides=2)(output_layer)
output_layer = BatchNormalization()(output_layer)
```

The truncation layer must satisfy:

```
−T if x < −T
x if −T ≤ x ≤ T
T  x > T 

where `T` is a threshold value, x= the output of convolution layer`
```

Could someone please help me to build this layer?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can build the desired function with `tensorflow.keras.backed.switch` and wrap it inside a `Lambda` layer

build and test the function:

```
T = 5
X = tf.constant(np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (3,5)))

def switch_func(X, T):
    
    zeros = tf.zeros_like(X)
    T_matrix = tf.ones_like(X) * T

    cond1 = K.switch(X < -T_matrix, -T_matrix, zeros)
    cond2 = K.switch(X > T_matrix, T_matrix, zeros)
    cond3 = K.switch(tf.abs(cond1 + cond2) == T, zeros, X)
    res = cond1 + cond2 + cond3
    return res

switch_func(X, T)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 5), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[-5.        ,  0.65807168, -4.93481499, -5.        , -2.94954848],
       [-1.25114075, -5.        ,  2.97657545,  5.        , -0.8958152 ],
       [-1.26611956,  5.        , -3.38477137,  5.        , -3.53358454]])>
```

usage inside the model:

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,10))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,))

inp = Input((10,))
x = Dense(8)(inp)
x = Lambda(lambda x: switch_func(x, T=0.5))(x)
out = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.fit(X,y, epochs=3)
```

Comment: Thank you Marco Cerliani  you answer is really what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.clip_by_value` and `tf.stop_gradient` to preserve the gradient, as `tf.clip_by_value` is not differentiable. FInally, wrap that in a `Lambda` layer :

```
import functools
def clip_preserve_grad(inp, clip_min, clip_max):
  return inp + tf.stop_gradient(tf.clip_by_value(inp, clip_min, clip_max) - inp)

T = 0.5
trunc_func = functools.partial(clip_preserve_grad, clip_min=-T, clip_max=T)
trunc = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(trunc_func)
```

Using the Lambda layer :

```
>>> a = tf.random.normal((1,10))
>>> a
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-1.8041286 , -0.11153453, -0.84555113,  0.8489615 ,  0.12237629,
         1.3350475 ,  0.619644  , -0.5498301 , -0.6082269 ,  0.8465021 ]],
      dtype=float32)>
>>> trunc(a)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.5       , -0.11153453, -0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.12237629,
         0.5       ,  0.5       , -0.5       , -0.5       ,  0.5       ]],
      dtype=float32)>
```